# Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a string variable ("1")

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.8

How can I get the name and not just the id?
This what actually I have in the datatable:
[Current Datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alNvS.png)

But what I nedd is show the name of the area NOT the id.
I tried to do this:

```
<table aria-describedby="dataTable_info" cellspacing="0" class="table table-hover dataTable" id="dataTable" role="grid" style="width:100%;" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Areas</th>
                                <th>Auditorias</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for audit in auditsByArea %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ audit.id_Area.name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ audit.Audits }} <input style="width:0.8cm; height:0.8cm;background-color:##E4E8E9; border-radius: 8px; border-color:#3A93B2"  class ="mx-2" data-id="4" data-area="{{ audit.id_Area }}"data-responsible="4" data-startDate="<?php date('n/d/Y');?>" id="auditBtn" name="auditBtn" type='text' readonly  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#auditModal"></input></td>
                                    </tr> 
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

But I get the following error:
**Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a string variable ("1").**

**Any Idea or Advice about whoe to fix it? or what is wrong?**

This is what I get whe I make a dump of AuditsByArea:

```
    array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id_Area' => string '1' (length=1)
      'Audits' => string '1,2,3,4' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id_Area' => string '3' (length=1)
      'Audits' => string '12,11,10,9' (length=10)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id_Area' => string '5' (length=1)
      'Audits' => string '17,18,19,20' (length=11)
```

**entity fsa_audits:**

```
        class FsaAudits
        {
            /**
             * @var int
             *
             * @ORM\Column(name="id_Audit", type="integer")
             * @ORM\Id
             * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
             */
            private $idAudit;

            /**
             * @var \DateTime
             *
             * @ORM\Column(name="StartDate", type="datetime")
             */
            private $StartDate;

            /**
             * @var \DateTime
             *
             * @ORM\Column(name="EndDate", type="datetime")
             */
            private $EndDate;

            /**
             * @var \DateTime
             *
             * @ORM\Column(name="DoneDate", type="datetime")
             */
            private $DoneDate;

            /**
             * @var string
             *
             * @ORM\Column(name="Status", type="string", length=255)
             */
            private $Status;

            /**
             * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\SECBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="audits", cascade={"persist"})
             * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_Auditor", referencedColumnName="id")
             */
            private $idAuditor;

            /**
             * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\FSABundle\Entity\FsaAreas", inversedBy="audits", cascade={"persist"})
             * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_Area", referencedColumnName="id_Area")
             */
            private $idArea;

            /**
             * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\FSABundle\Entity\FsaPlans", inversedBy="audits", cascade={"persist"})
             * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_PlanFsa", referencedColumnName="id_PlanFsa")
             */
            private $idPlanFsa;

           /**
             * @var string
             *
             * @ORM\Column(name="Grade", type="string", length=255)
             */
            private $Grade;

            /**
             * @var string
             * 
             * @ORM\Column(name="Comments", type="string", length=250)
             */
            private $Comments;

            /**
             * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\FSABundle\Entity\FsaLayers", inversedBy="audits", cascade={"persist"})
             * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Frequency", referencedColumnName="id_Layer")
             */
            private $Frequency;
    Getters and Setters...
        }
```

**Entity fsa_Areas:**

```
    class FsaAreas
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_Area", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $idArea;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean")
     */
    private $enabled;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="division", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $division;

    /**
     * @var \FSABundle\Entity\FsaLayers
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\FSABundle\Entity\FsaLayers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="frequency", referencedColumnName="id_Layer")
     */
    private $frequency;

    /**
     * @var \SCTBundle\Entity\FosUser
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\SCTBundle\Entity\FosUser", inversedBy="areas",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="responsible", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $responsible;

    /**
     * @var \FSABundle\Entity\FsaPlants
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\FSABundle\Entity\FsaPlants", inversedBy="areas",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_Plant", referencedColumnName="id_Plant")
     */
    private $idPlant;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\FSABundle\Entity\FsaQuestions", mappedBy="areas")
     */
    private $questions;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="asigned", type="boolean")
     */
    public $asigned;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\FSABundle\Entity\FsaAudits", mappedBy="idArea")
     */
    private $audits;
Getters and Setters...
}
```

[Table of fsa_Areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkWnu.png)

[Table of fsa_Audits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCIDc.png)

Comment: Maybe {{ audit.Area.name }} ?

Comment: Please post output of `{{dump(auditsByArea)}}`

Comment: sorry, I'm loading the data from this query: $query = "SELECT id_Area,GROUP_CONCAT(id_Audit) as Audits FROM helios.fsa_audits where id_Auditor='$AuditorId' GROUP BY id_Area;";
        $stm = $em->getConnection()->prepare($query);
        $stm->execute();
        $auditsByArea = $stm->fetchAll();

Comment: SELECT id_Area, areaname, ecc ?

Comment: You are trying to access a property that does not exist ("name"), in your select you have only id_Area

Comment: I edited my question with the dump of the auditsByArea

Comment: How can I load the whole object if I'm using a group_concat?

Comment: Where is name? Table name?

Comment: I added in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your comment you wrote, your query is:

```
SELECT id_Area, GROUP_CONCAT(id_Audit) as Audits 
FROM helios.fsa_audits 
WHERE id_Auditor='$AuditorId' 
GROUP BY id_Area;
```

add the information you want to output:

```
SELECT id_Area, area.Name as area_name, GROUP_CONCAT(id_Audit) as Audits 
FROM helios.fsa_audits 
LEFT JOIN helios.fas_areas area USING (id_Area)
WHERE id_Auditor='$AuditorId' 
GROUP BY id_Area;
```

and you can access it in your loop via:

```
{{ audit.area_name }}
```

note, however, that you're using plain php arrays, with a "manual" sql query and none of the functions that doctrine's ORM provides.