# How can I generate this query in doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, query-builder, symfony-2.8

How can I generate this query in doctrine or query builder?

```
SELECT EndDate from helios.fsa_audits order by StartDate desc limit 1;
```

Any idea or Advice about how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your entity [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909798/impossible-to-access-an-attribute-name-on-a-string-variable-1), in your controller you can try this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select(array('a'))
        ->from(FsaAudits::class, 'a')
        ->orderBy("a.StartDate","DESC")
        ->setMaxResults(1);
$resultset = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
if (count($resultset) <= 0) {
    $fsaobj = $resultset[0];
    echo $fsaobj->getEndDate();
}
```

See [Working with query builder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#working-with-querybuilder)